# Is there a good way to optimize data modelling, running total and running percentages in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have Table 1 below with about 100K portfolios and 1000 members. My task is to find the earliest date each member will expect to have 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% completion and the earliest date that each member has actually had 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% completion.

Table 1 - Detailed Report

```
|PortfolioID| MemberName  | ReportingQuarter | ExpectedCompletionDate | CompletionDate | Status**
|     1     |      A      |      03/31/2023  |   4/3/2023             |    4/3/2023     | Done 
|     2     |      A      |      03/31/2023  |   4/4/2023             |    4/4/2023     | Done
|     3     |      A      |      03/31/2023  |   4/5/2023             |    4/5/2023     | Done
|     4     |      A      |      03/31/2023  |   4/6/2023             |    4/6/2023     | Done
|     1     |      B      |      03/31/2023  |   4/3/2023             |    4/3/2023     | Done 
|     2     |      B      |      03/31/2023  |   4/4/2023             |    4/4/2023     | Done
|     3     |      B      |      03/31/2023  |   4/5/2023             |    4/5/2023     | Done
|     4     |      B      |      03/31/2023  |   4/6/2023             |     NULL        | Not Done
```

To improve Power BI performance, I ran 3 SQL queries: the above detailed report query, the earliest expected date with 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% completion query and the actual date with 70%, 80%, 90%, 100% completion query.

Table 2 - Earliest Expected Completion Date at 70%, 80%, 90%, 100%

```
|MemberName | ReportingQuarter | EarliestExpectedCompletionDate| Completion%
|     A     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/5/2023      |          70%
|     A     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/6/2023      |          80%
|     A     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/6/2023      |          90%
|     A     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/6/2023     |          100%
|     B     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/5/2023      |          70%
|     B     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/6/2023      |          80%
|     B     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/6/2023      |          90%
|     B     |  03/31/2023      |                 4/6/2023      |          100%
```

Table 3 - Actual Completion Date at 70%, 80%, 90%, 100%

```
|MemberName | ReportingQuarter | ActualCompletionDate  |      Completion%
|     A    |   03/31/2023      |   4/5/2023              |             70% 
|     A    |   03/31/2023      |   4/6/2023              |             80% 
|     A    |   03/31/2023      |   4/6/2023              |             90% 
|     A    |   03/31/2023      |   4/6/2023              |             100% 
|     B    |    03/31/2023     |   4/5/2023              |             70%
```

My Dim tables are MemberDim, DateDim, Completion%Dim. The slicers in my dashboard are from the Dim Tables: **Member Name, Reporting Quarter, Completion Date, Completion %**. The goal is when the users pick the Completion % for that quarter, it will show many members that expect to reach and how many members actually reached 70% at the Completion Date in that quarter, how many portfolios there are, how many are done and not done.

However, I run into several issues: when selecting the slicers, the numbers of portfolios, members, reporting quarter, completion % in the result table are incorrect, the Completion Date and Completion % slicers either give values in Table 2 or Table 3 and not both, all Reporting Quarters appear in the result and not just the selected reporting quarter.

I hope there is a solution to my issue and the issue is explained clear enough. Please let me know if I need to precise some things, and feel free if you have a totally different solution for my issue.